# Improve the robustness of Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

I ran into an unexpected phenomenon in my shiny application.
 I have reduced thousands lines of code to roughly 200, cannot further reduce without breaking a pattern that cause the problem, see below:

[gist for minimal example](https://gist.github.com/happyshows/85bfa045c432c877b427e5a060b74beb)

The intention of code was to be able to call modules dynamically via button + insertUI, each module has utility function to load data via modalDialog. Once 'Load Data' button is triggered, data will be fetched to react_src().

However, in my attempt, there are two major issues:

1) The module works in the first time when 'Call' button is triggered, it does not try to render correctly the 2nd time 'Call' button is clicked.
 By looking at the browser console, it seems to have some duplicated binding issue (and literally crashing this app for further operations), which I failed to understand why it happened.
The weird thing is, if I do cancel the modalDialog, and directly click 'Call' button again, then there's no binding issues for the 2nd trigger, 3rd trigger and etc.

2) The following test code did not work when user clicks the 'placeholder' Button, it should be a straightforward one...

```
observe({
  req(input$mb_inputs)
  isolate({
    print(input$mb_inputs)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix and explanation here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/1402

There was a low-level bug in Shiny that is triggered when you use `insertUI` and have nested `uiOutput` at or near the insertion point. Basically, after the HTML is inserted, Shiny finds all `uiOutput` elements nearby and iterates over them. In the case of nested `uiOutput`, it was possible for some of the elements in the list to be nested inside other elements in the list. That's normally OK, but not if processing an outer, earlier element causes a later, inner element to be removed from the DOM (which is what was happening in your case).